# Can I bring a firearm into NJ?

Tags: new-jersey, firearms

If I'm planning to visit some family in NJ would it be legal for me to bring a pistol that is locked in a container into the state?

I've found information saying that it should not be an issue if I'm traveling through the state but may be an issue if I'm stopping in the state?  There are several conflicting pieces of information around it that make me too unsure to try and interpret myself.

Comment: No idea, but it may be wise to contact a NJ liscensed gun dealer and ask.  They would know the Transportaion laws and be able to help you transport your personal firearm in the best way possible.  It may also be wise to make sure you can legally carry your firearm in the state of New Jersey.

Answer (score 1):

From [Firearms Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ's) | New Jersey State Police](https://nj.gov/njsp/firearms/firearms-faqs.shtml)

> 25: Can I travel through New Jersey with my firearms?
>
> Yes.  With no unreasonable deviations from your travels you may drive
> through New Jersey with any type firearm or ammunition.  If New Jersey
> is the State of destination, then the firearms must be legal in this
> State.

and

> 6: How do you transport firearms?
>
> Firearms shall be carried unloaded and contained in a closed and
> fastened case, gunbox, securely tied package, or locked in the trunk
> of the automobile in which it is being transported.  If the vehicle
> does not have a compartment separate from the passenger compartment,
> the firearm and or ammunition shall be in a locked container other
> than the vehicle's glove compartment or center console and kept
> farthest from the driver.
>
> As a precaution, ammunition shall be transported in a separate
> container and locked in the trunk of the automobile in which it is
> being transported.  Ammunition magazines may remain loaded during
> transportation and shall be carried separate from the firearm.

Unless, of course, the gun is a type simply illegal to own in NJ, such as an assault rifle, automatic rifle, etc. This may be dated, but outlines what firearms are illegal: [A Guide to Legal Firearms Possession in New Jersey - HG.org](https://www.hg.org/legal-articles/a-guide-to-legal-firearms-possession-in-new-jersey-51287).

See also [New Jersey State Police - NJ Firearm Laws - N.J.A.C. Title 13 Chapter 54 - Firearms and Weapons - njac-title13-ch54.pdf](https://www.state.nj.us/njsp/info/pdf/firearms/njac-title13-ch54.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you study this page and it's links carefully as New Jersey has notoriously arbitrary and complex gun laws and enforcement:

[HandgunLaw NJ](https://handgunlaw.us/states/newjersey.pdf)

Specifically this:

> New Jersey Law also states that before possessing or transporting any
> rifle or shotgun without first having obtained a New Jersey firearms
> purchaser identification card (FPIC), or possessing or transporting
> any handgun without first having obtained a New Jersey handgun carry
> permit is a violation of their law. You can transport it from place of
> purchase to home. Home to a Certified Shooting Range. Going hunting
> but must have a valid hunting license. You just can’t have it in your
> vehicle. Again the law says you must have a FPIC or NJ Carry Permit to
> even transport firearms in NJ. From all I read and have heard someone
> from outside NJ must have a very good reason to transport a firearm
> into NJ and better have the proper paperwork.